# Pictures on Stack Overflow are blurry with 4K ultra HD screen

Tags: support

I've just purchased a new laptop with 4K ultra HD (3840x2160) resolution. Everything is fine with Stack Overflow except pictures. They are blurry. On the CNN website, images are extremely clean. Is there a way to fix it?

I've done some research and it seems some applications are suffering from high DPI screens. Some people say, developers of these applications need to update their products to work with such high resolution screens. Even [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) suffers from this issue on Windows. My OS is [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) and the brand is Acer and the graphics card is Nvidia. See the picture below as an example.

[image]

Comment: could you link to where the image originate from?

Comment: I see nothing particularly blurry there. Or at least, not anything more blurry than I would expect from taking a low-resolution image and magnifying it with a linear interpolation filter. So... what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: If that was a user-uploaded image, I'm not sure how SE could possibly make that higher res then it actually is, which still would look blurry.

Comment: Also, stackoverflow is not an "app". Its a website. And I don't think increasing stock image file size (== higher load time) for this niche case (not many people are using these monitors w/o upsampling) would be worth it.

Comment: A site like CNN can solve the problem of widely varying resolutions (4k to 1080p to tablet to mobile phone) because they have full control over all the content on their website and thus can provide the same image in different resolutions. But the images under discussion here are provided by users; one image, one resolution.

Comment: It has been generated by Tikz.

Comment: 4k Ultra HD... first world problems! For the record I have a potato monitor and the linked image is blurry on that too.

Comment: @CroCo Thats not true. What you describe as "blurry" is in fact missing resolution. What you think are "high resolution images" are probably just upscaled in an attempt to make them less directly blurry.

Comment: @NicolBolas, are you using 4K screen?

Comment: @Tanner, what is a potato monitor?

Comment: @CroCo it was a joke, meaning i had a bad/old monitor...

Comment: @CroCo: "*It has been generated by Tikz.*" Did you generate it at a sufficiently high resolution? Is Tikz even capable of generating high resolution images? Because the image you're showing is *not* the result of a high-resolution rasterization of a vector graphics image. It is clearly the result of scaling up an image from a low resolution. The *inevitable result* of that process is added blur/noise/artifacts.

Answer (score 6):

User posted images on Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites are controlled by the users that upload them. They choose the resolution, and outside of magnifying/upscaling them, there is very little Stack Exchange can do about that.

So if a user uploaded image looks blurry to you, thats because the user uploaded it in that lower resolution. CNN doesn't have this problem because they fully control any image on their site, and they can provide higher-res copies for the people with higher resolution monitors.

Comment: all images are blurry with my screen whether high or low resolutions images.

Comment: @CroCo can you link to an example of a high resolution image uploaded by a user to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Pekka웃, yes I can generate a high resolution image via Tikz. Actually, the image I've posted it is mine.

Comment: @CroCo So that was a high-res image before you uploaded it? What dimensions did it have?... it would appear that the imgur uploader resizes the image then. To ask for that to be removed is a fair feature request - although I imagine it might get rejected because it would multiply traffic numbers, and the number of people uploading material in the resolution required would likely be very small